# How to get background color of a dialog/window?

Tags: qt, pyqt

How to get background color of a dialog/window in RGB format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `QWidget::palette` to access widget's palette and `QPalette::color` to obtain the background color:

```
color = widget.palette().color(QPalette.Background)
print color.red(), color.green(), color.blue()
```

Comment: typo: `QPalette::Background` actually

Comment: No, it's `.` in Python.

Answer (score 2):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#palette-prop

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum

> QPalette::Window   - 10    - A general background color.

`QPixmap::grabWindow();` can get you any part of the desktop.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWin(QtGui.QDialog):
   def __init__(self,parent=None):
      QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
      pal=QtGui.QPalette()
      role = QtGui.QPalette.Background
      pal.setColor(role, QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
      self.setPalette(pal)
```

or with stylesheet

```
      self.setStyleSheet("background:blue)
```

Comment: OP was asking how to get the color, not how to set.